# How to access input coordinates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, image, input, coordinates

```
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<input type='text' id='jak'  value='1' style='position:absolute ; top:400px; '/>";
        
    ?>
    <input type="IMAGE" name="Baadee" id="Baadee" src="Baadee.png" style="position: absolute ; left: 795px ; top:50px ;">

    <script>
      if (document.getElementById("jak").value == 1) {

        document.getElementById("Baadee").style.top = 650;
      }
    </script>
```

Hi, I am running this code but it does not go to 650 coordinates.

Comment: What about the units??

Answer (score 3):

When you set the top value of a style, it should be a string that ends in "px". I would update your code thus: `document.getElementById("Baadee").style.top = "650px"`